# Readind from a CSV file and writing to a new CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

Explanation: I need to take parameters from file1 and need to use in some function and then i need to take results from that function then need to write these test_name and results to a new csv i.e file2. while iam doing with below example iam getting some errors.

Readind from a CSV file1 and writing to a new CSV file2 using python

```
with open(inputs.csv, 'rb') as file1:  #Need to read params from this file
    data = list(csv.reader(file1))
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as file2: #Need to write results to this file
    writer = csv.writer(file2)
for row in data:
    api = row[0]
    test_name =row[1]
    out = funtion_call(api, test_name)
    writer.writerow([test_name, out])
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Output:

```
 writer.writerow([test_name, out])
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: Please paste the exact error message and traceback in your question, "some errors" is not a very useful information!

Comment: just use `pandas`

Comment: Installing `pandas` just for the sake of reading a csv file is overkill...

Comment: `with open(inputs.csv, 'rb') as file1:`
Maybe this should be:
`with open('inputs.csv', 'r') as file1:`. Also why 'rb' and 'wb'? You are reading a glorified text file. Not a bytes files.

Comment: hi @selten98, when iam using a single file only for read from csv i.e file1 its worked fine with 'rb'. any way i tried with your suggession as well but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `with` statment, your operations need to be within that block, `with` handles the opening and closing for you.

```
with open(inputs.csv, 'rb') as file1:  
    data = list(csv.reader(file1))
    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as file2: 
        writer = csv.writer(file2)
        for row in data:
        api = row[0]
        test_name =row[1]
        out = funtion_call(api, test_name)
        writer.writerow([test_name, out])
```

Without all your code, it is impossible to test this, but hopefully you get the idea.  This link might help too: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: true, but `with open(inputs.csv, 'rb') as file1, open('output.csv', 'wb') as file2` seems much more readable - especially because there is one level of indentation fewer...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, I agree, that would be a more readable solution and would work better if there are a lot of operations on the two files.